# Keeping Java Server Session Live in Flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, session

I need to keep the session active when the user is working on my application. Application is connecting to Java using webserivce. I have a service to keep/ check server session active/timeout. Which is the best approach to achieve this? I checked for the

```
systemManager FlexEvent.IDLE event
```

but didn't suite my need. Any workaround for this??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a HeartBeatMonitor.as class who's sole responsibility is to react to responses from the server and carry on beating if a response was successful.

Off the top of my head you would want this class to implement IResponder and have a timer for the delay between the heartbeats.

HeartBeatMonitor + HeartBeatCommand (for making call) = client side session keep alive

Comment: Thanks MM,
But in that case, how will I stop pinging if the user keeps idle for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write your own java server? If so, you should open a socket in server side and wait for connection. After that you can create your protocol which is between server and clients. And then you should decide when to close your connection/session in server-side. IF I didn't misunderstood, you can check  [How to write server side java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

Comment: Anil,
The issue is with the flex side, that i need to add some eventhandler that keep calling a service in fixed interval to keep my session active. Once the user was idle and and he cam back, it should again ping back to check if timeout occurred.